# how get thumbnails from video and send it as a response using ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, and express js

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg, thumbnails, fluent-ffmpeg

am using ffmpeg with fluent-ffmpeg to get a thumbnail from a video like this

```
ffmpeg({
  source: `../../uploadedVideo/${filepath}`,
}).takeScreenshots({
  filename: "example.jpg",
  timemarks: [2, 4, 6, 8],
  folder: "../../thumbnail/",
});
```

but what i wanna do is instead of saving the thumbnail to a folder i wanna send it as an
api response , here is the whole code.

```
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

router.post("/upload", (req, res) => {

  const file = req.files.video;
  const filepath = `${uuid()}${path.extname(file.name)}`;
  
  // imagine the file is saved to the server at this point
  
  ffmpeg({
    source: `../../uploadedVideo/${filepath}`,
  }).takeScreenshots({
    filename: "example.jpg",
    timemarks: [2, 4, 6, 8],
    folder: "../../thumbnail/",
  });

  res.send({ msg: "success", thumbnail });

});
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "send it as an api response" do you want to receive the jpg files as a byte array directly from ffmpeg instead of you reading the thumbnail file?

Comment: so right now its saving the images to a file in a folder but like you said i wanna receive the jpg files as a byte array directly from ffmpeg and send it as a response. can i use pipe() here?

Answer (score 0):

In FFmpeg, the following is what you need to run for each screenshot time `t`:

```
ffmpeg -ss t -i source.mp4 -f mjpeg -vframe 1 -s wxh -
```

and subprocess' stdout spits out jpeg data with the frame size of width `w` by height `h`. So you need to call this line 4 times, at `t = 2, 4, 6, & 8` (and that's actually what `fluent-ffmpeg` does.

Now, the part I'm not sure is how all this translates to `fluent-ffmpeg`. You're correct, you need to use `pipe()`. Here is my rough take (I haven't used JavaScript in years so forgive me if I mess something up)

```js
var outStream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/output.mp4');

ffmpeg(`../../uploadedVideo/${filepath}`)
  .format('mjpeg') // -f mjpeg
  .frames(1) // -vframes 1
  .size('320x240') // -s 320x240 : w = 320, h = 240
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('Processing finished !');
  })
  .pipe(outStream, { end: true });
```

I modified an example on `fluent-ffmpeg` documentation.